# Is Studio Controls available in Ubuntu Studio 23.10 and beyond?

Tags: ubuntu-studio, cpufreq, 23.10, governor

I have been testing Ubuntu Studio 23.10.  During the testing, I could not find Studio Controls, which has been available for some time in Ubuntu Studio.  Is it installed? If not, is the CPU Governor functionality available in another Ubuntu Studio app?  I realize that I can edit the CPU governor by line command; obviously it's much easier with a GUI.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=studio-controls&searchon=names&suite=mantic&section=all

Comment: Thanks! I found how to get what I wanted.  I'll have to check pipewire to see if I can set the cpu governor from there.

Comment: You should also take a look at [this page](https://ubuntustudio.org/switching-audio-setup/).